# Error with Production environment in Angular 4

Tags: angular, build, certificate, production-environment

I have the following errors in the Production environment. can anybody help me?

```
Este site usa um certificado SHA-1; é recomendado o uso de certificados com 
os algoritmos da assinatura que usem funções hash mais fortes que SHA-1.
[Learn More]  10.116.82.86:8014
BsDatepickerModule is under development,
BREAKING CHANGES are possible,
PLEASE, read changelog  vendor.bundle.js:13670:5
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable 
the production mode.  vendor.bundle.js:56930:9
Carregando conteúdo ativo mesclado (inseguro) "http://localhost:8080/projeto-
web-api-1.0.0/web/login" em uma página segura[Learn More]  
polyfills.bundle.js:5478:12
Carregando conteúdo ativo mesclado (inseguro) "http://localhost:8080/projeto-
web-api-1.0.0/web/login" em uma página segura[Learn More]  10.116.82.86:8014
Erro 0 ao acessar a URL null -   main.bundle.js:688:17
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can read

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

I'm going to say you're not in production mode.